# Symfony2 - How to share/reuse forms, entities and validations between Api and Client/Frontend

Tags: php, api, rest, symfony

I would really like an pointers, answers from experience on how to reuse Form Types, Entities(object) and Validation constrains between backend API and some other frontend / client code.

Specificaly:
I have an managed entity lets say Product.php.
A ProductType.php with form definitions and validation rules for the entity in validation.yml.

I take these into separate repository, and require them with composer inside my Api and Client code.
The response from Api will be the serialized Product object. On the client side I would deserialize from json to the same Product, but this time without access to any db layer, eg. an unmanaged plain object.

So the question is did anyone manage to reuse these components in similar setting, or point to some resources how to manage this?
The usecase would be: centralized place for object code. Faster client implementations etc.

So far the main problem I stumbled upon is how to manage relations, when defined in the form, with the entity/choice type, as the entity type requires managed object by doctrine. An the choice type doesn't know how to use array of objects as choices.

Is this even worth the trouble, or is better to have almost identical code on both api and client side?

Example objects follows:
`

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
 {
    $builder->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('price', 'text')

            // use PRE_SET_DATA EVENT to determine if entity or choice here
            // this should be used on the server side, with access to db
            ->add('tags', 'entity', [
                'class'        => 'Acme\MyBundle\Tag',
                'multiple'     => true
             ]);
            // This should be used in the client, without access to db
            //->add('tags', 'choice', [
            //    'data_class' => 'Acme\MyBundle\Tag',
            //    'choices'    => $arrayOfTagObjects,
            //    'multiple'   => true
            // ]);
}
```

}
`

Comment: Are you using forms in your api? i.e: Are both field types (entity and choice) going to be used in your forms? Cause if you're only using it clientside it will always be a choice type.

Comment: @user2268997 - that the point.. I want to use the above form both on server and client side. Decide with PRE_SET_DATA if it would be entity or choice field. Will update the code sample for it to be clearer.

Comment: How do you want to do that using PRE_SET_DATA? i.e: how are you going to find out if the submitted data is from the server or the client?

Comment: @user2268997 - Well i can check if the object is managed by doctrine or not. If it isnt, its in the client.. And maybe better way would be to add setters to the form type, and manualy set the data. Eg . setEntities / setObject .. and decide based on the supplied data.. There are many ways really.

Comment: I think you MUST enforce some convention server side for e.g: submitting the data on the form, to automatically be able to detect where the form is submitted.(unless you want to hook into `FormInterface::handleRequest`).Nevertheless this is an interesting approach. By sacrificing some generality (and elegance) you could add an option to all you forms (with a form extension) to create the right the form in the `buildForm` method to build on the form based on the value of that option, which tells you if your form is created for the API or the UI.(kind of like your `setEntity` approach)

Comment: BTW symfony's forms are one of the slowest components of symfony, so you could ditch that Server side and only use the validator.